# MaxMind Creative Commons License

Tags: geoip, maxmind

I have a question about the license of MaxMind GeoLite2 Free.
I just want to use the database to get the user country to show them some content filtered by country.

MaxMind site says this:

> The attribution requirement may be met by including the following in
>   all advertising and documentation mentioning features of or use of
>   this database

I won't mention the database ever, it just a background process. Do I need to put the attribution link anyway?

Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software licensing and not programming as defined in the [help] pages. It may be more suitable for another site such as [programmers.se], where they allow some types of licensing questions. Please check the [Programmers Help Center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help) before posting there, though. (With that being said, the license is for *using it*; it makes no difference if you show the results or not. Using the database is using the database.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the attribution if you use it.